# changing kernel of Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

everyone, I'm trying to learn how to work with Kernel of the Linux Red Hat, I tried to change some function from kernel:

```
/*
 * sys_execve() executes a new program.
 */
asmlinkage int sys_execve(struct pt_regs regs)
{
    int error;
    char * filename;



    filename = getname((char *) regs.ebx);
    error = PTR_ERR(filename);
    if (IS_ERR(filename))
        goto out;

    printk("Hello World!"); // I added this function

    error = do_execve(filename, (char **) regs.ecx, (char **) regs.edx, &regs);
    if (error == 0)
        current->ptrace &= ~PT_DTRACE;
    putname(filename);
out:
    return error;
}
```

this system call executes programs, my question why while I'm in terminal and writing some function for example 'date' I don't receive my hello world, thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`printk()` should be logged to `/proc/kmsg`, which in turn is read and logged by `syslog(8)`.

Comment: In general the kernel does not write to terminals directly, except for the console (`Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1`), and even that only during system boot.  You include a log level, which is a number enclosed in `<>` at the start of the string, and let `syslogd` decide where to send it (see `syslog.conf(5)`; this will depend on what syslog package is used on your distribution).  Don't try to change this or force the issue; aside from being obnoxious, there are some interesting locking and timing issues involved (consider what happens if you press `Ctrl`+`s` in the middle of it writing the log message).

Comment: I've noticed that either the kernel or some daemon, will write to my console when I insert or remove a USB drive.

Comment: @Tom: That will generally be `udevd`; the kernel logs some information to `syslogd` as described above, but I don't think `syslogd` generally logs that to the console.